# Regular expression for matching the words following a phrase

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have many plain text files that I am trying to clean and reformat. I am using regex to match and remove unwanted content.

All the files have a legal disclaimer in them that looks something like this: "This work is in the  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/en:public_domain' class='extiw' title=..."

Because these disclaimers only appear at the end of the document, I have tried to make a regex that will match the phrase "This work is in the" and all characters following that phrase. Then I am substituting the match with black space, which, to my knowledge, should basically delete the disclaimer.

I currently have this:

```
for file in os.listdir(r'C:\Example'):
    temp_file = open(file, "r+")
    file_text = temp_file.read()
    file_text = re.sub("<[^>]*>", "", file_text)  # Removes html in the text
    file_text = re.sub(r"\.\D", "\n", file_text)  # Puts each sentence on a new line
    file_text = re.sub(r"[^\w\s]", "", file_text)  # Removes punctuation
    file_text = re.sub("This work is in the.*", "", file_text)  # Removes public domain disclaimer

    temp_file.seek(0)  # Goes to the top of the file before writing to it
    temp_file.write(file_text)
    temp_file.close()
```

To my understanding, `file_text = re.sub("This work is in the.*", "", file_text)` should match and delete the part I want before writing the new text to the file, but this is not working.

If I print `file_text` before writing to the new file, the end of the print out looks like this:

```
'In these and all other matters which you in your wisdom may propose for the '
 'good of our country you may count with assurance on my hearty cooperation '
 'and faithful execution\n'
 ' \n'
 '\n'
 '\n'
 '160105 \n')
```

When I actually open the text file I see this:

> In these and all other matters which you in your wisdom may propose
>   for the good of our country you may count with assurance on my hearty
>   cooperation and faithful execution
>
> 160105  all other matters which you in your wisdom may propose for the
>   good of our country you may count with assurance on my hearty
>   cooperation and faithful execution.', 'This work is in the...

Does anyone know what's going on here? How should I format the final regex statement to make this work?

Comment: In face, your final call to `re.sub` should be doing what you want.  What is currently happening, if it is not working as planned?

Comment: I updated the post with more information, including an example of what the final text file looks like. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

```
file_text = re.sub(".*This work is in the.*", "", file_text)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not seem to solve the issue. I updated the post with more information about the specifics of the problem I'm facing. Thank you for your help.